# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function React with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I know there are tons of similar topics but I was not able to fix my problem.

I am getting this error for my mapDispatchToProps:

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

This is my component:
component/AddQuestions.js:

```
import React from "react";
import QuestionList from "./QuestionList";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const AddQuestions2 = ({ questions, addQuestion }) => {
  let newQuestion;

  function handleAdd(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(newQuestion);
    addQuestion(newQuestion);
  }

  function handleChange(e) {
    newQuestion = e.target.value;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Questions</h2>
      <QuestionList questions={questions} />
      <form onSubmit={handleAdd}>
        <label htmlFor="new-question">Enter new Question:</label>
        <input id="new-question" onChange={handleChange} value={newQuestion} />
        <button>Add Question #</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

AddQuestions2.propTypes = {
  questions: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  addQuestion: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default AddQuestions2;
```

This is my container:
container/AddQuestions.js:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import AddQuestion from "../components/AddQuestions";
import { addQuestion } from "../redux/actions";

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  questions: ["test1", "test2"]
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addQuestion: question => dispatch(addQuestion(question))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddQuestion);
```

The action I want to connect:
reducers/index.js:

```
export const addQuestion = question => ({
    type: "ADD_QUESTION",
    question
})
```

I am using this versions:

```
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"react-scripts": "3.4.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
```

I tried to follow the setup of the official redux repo on Github, but yes they are using a different redux version:

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos/

Error message in console:

```
react-dom.development.js:327 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at addQuestion (AddQuestions.js:10)
    at handleAdd (AddQuestions.jsx:53)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:306)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:389)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:414)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:3278)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:3287)
    at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:3259)
    at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:3304)
    at runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:3514)
    at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:3558)
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21871)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:795)
    at dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:3568)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4267)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4189)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:697)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21887)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:806)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:4168)
```

Additional information:

CreateQuestion.js:

```
import React from "react";
import AddDetails from "./AddDetails";
import AddQuestion from "../containers/AddQuestions";
import QuestionList from "./QuestionList";

class CreateQuestion extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AddDetails />
        <AddQuestion />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CreateQuestion;
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import CreateQuestion from "./components/CreateQuestion";

function App() {
  return <CreateQuestion />;
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "./redux/configureStore";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

QuestionList.jsx

```
import React from "react";

class QuestionList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.questions.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default QuestionList;
```

Comment: Try to install `redux` as a dependency.

Comment: thanks, I just did and updated my question. But still get the same error.

Comment: Can you add here the error that you are getting in your console?

Comment: thanks, yes I added it just now

Comment: @PaFi can you also show us how you are importing AddQuestion and where are you using it?

Comment: yes of course, thanks, I added some new information

Comment: please provide the QuestionList  component

Comment: I presume that you only have exports/imports problem. please add files names with the content you provided

Comment: The error indicates that react is trying to call a function, but fails because it s not a function, so I presume it s import/export issue.

Comment: I added the filenames, can you see any import error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `mapDispatchToProps` like below

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addQuestion,
};
```

It have to wrap you callback in dispatch automatically.

Also you can try to log you `addQuestion` function before pass it to `mapDispatchToProps`.
Does it work or not? What does it print? If it's undefined, then you imported it wrong.

```js
import { addQuestion } from "../redux/actions";
console.log(addQuestion); // undefined?
```

Comment: yes indeed its prints undefined, do I maybe have to initialise the action? or how do I import it correctly, in the linked github repo it seems they are doing it the same why but using a todo.spec.js file

Comment: @PaFi Is `addQuestion` action located in `redux/actions/index.js` or `redux/actions.js`?

Comment: @PaFi if not there is a problem

Comment: @PaFi Try to `import actions from "../redux/actions"` and log it: `console.log(actions)`. What do you see?

Comment: addQuestion action is located in redux/actions/index.js

Comment: if i import actions from "../redux/actions" it returns an object but not undefined

Comment: but yes its an import error because if I put the addQuestion in the same file it works

Comment: I didnt change anything, but the import works now. Thanks!

Comment: @PaFi no problems :)